# Boostrap3 form doesn't send the POST request to the view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying make a simple Sign Up form, with Bootstrap3 and Django 1.6.2. What's happen is that the view doesn't receive de POST request and I didn't find nothing about my problem.

home.html

```
<form class="form-signup" method="post" action="/sign_up/" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-signup-heading">Sign Up Now...</h2>
    <input type="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

view.py

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.POST.get('username')
    else:
        print "get"
```

This view method is just for debug. 
Someone have any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: Try form with `action=""`

Comment: Please post your urls.py

Comment: It's working now. I defined the form with Django and pass it from the view to the template, and then use {% bootstrap_form form %}. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but would just like to point out that none of your inputs or buttons have `name` attributes, which would cause them not to be present in the post data.